# angular2 with typescript and ng-content, what's my scope?

Tags: typescript, angular

So i have something like the following with a parent and child component defined in their own files:

**Parent**

```
/// <reference path="angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angular2/core.d.ts" />

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template:
    '<div>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>'
})
export class Parent{
    parentDiagnostic(){
        return "this is the parent scope!";
    }
}

bootstrap(Parent);
```

**Child**

```
/// <reference path="angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angular2/core.d.ts" />

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template:
    '<div>
        <h1>{{parentDiagnostic()}}</h1>
        <h1>{{childDiagnostic()}}</h1>
    </div>'
})
export class Child{
    childDiagnostic() {
        return "this is a child!";
    }
}

bootstrap(Child);
```

Which i use like this:

```
<parent>
    <child></child>
</parent>
```

Why is parentDiagnostic() valid in child scope but childDiagnostic() is not? shouldn't it be the opposite? the parent and child don't need to communicate, but html is embedded. How do you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-content` is not documented, but there are a lot of very simple examples that are quite misleading.

`ng-content` is projection target within component template, projected content itself belongs to template where it was declared and so are all template variables and methods.

In your case root template is declared directly on html page, so its owner is Parent component (as the top most component), so all template vars are resolved against Parent component.

Comment: In another word, you can't have multi-view components?

Comment: Angular2 way is to use `DynamicComponentLoader`, there were plans to support multiple templates also.